# update line in js file with sed

Tags: bash, sh

I have this line in a file called core.js:

```
  VERSION: '1.2.3-0',
```

I also have a variable called `VERSION`.

In a .sh script that I'm writing I want to update `VERSION: '1.2.3-0',` with the version so that it would look like `VERSION: '1.2.4',` (or whatever vallue it's set to).

I've tried this but it did not work:

```
sed 's/\b^VERSION: '[^']/$VERSION/' core.js
```

How do I update this line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the following command:

```
sed -i "s|VERSION: '1.2.3-0'|VERSION: '1.2.4'|g" core.js
```

When you run `sed` without the -i option it will just output the difference rather than apply the change.